# Rails-customize confirm dialog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, confirmation, customdialog

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icon_delete.png", :border => 0), user, method: :delete ,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure delete ' + user.email } %>
```

When user clicks on this link, I want a custom confirm dialog instead of simply showing `confirm('Are you are')`.

I've read many threads, for example http://lesseverything.com/blog/archives/2012/07/18/customizing-confirmation-dialog-in-rails/.  However, I hit on issue `Sprockets::EncodingError`.

Any better solution?

**UPDATE**

Everything ok before implemented customized confirmation dialog,After encoding successful, This time

```
<%= link_to image_tag("icon_delete.png", :border => 0), user, method: :delete ,data: { confirm: 'Are you sure delete ' + user.email } %>
```

Actually,When I click on delete icon,no popup show and this link didn't call destroy() in UserController.It called show() on UserController.What's going on here?

```
$.rails.allowAction = (link) ->
return true unless link.attr('data-confirm')
$.rails.showConfirmDialog(link) # look bellow for implementations
false # always stops the action since code runs asynchronously

$.rails.confirmed = (link) ->
link.removeAttr('data-confirm')
link.trigger('click.rails')


$.rails.showConfirmDialog = (link) ->
message = link.attr 'data-confirm'
html = """
     <div class="modal" id="confirmationDialog">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Ã—</a>
         <h3>Are you sure Mr. President?</h3>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
         <p>#{message}</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
         <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Cancel</a>
         <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary confirm">OK</a>
       </div>
     </div>
     """
$(html).modal()
$('#confirmationDialog .confirm').on 'click', -> $.rails.confirmed(link)
```

File route.rb
     root :to => "users#index"

```
 devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users"}
 resources :users
 match '/admin',   to: 'users#admin',   via: 'get'
```

Comment: You really shouldn't... Building your own dialogs is a terrible practice. You're only going to make your site less mobile-friendly/accessible.

Comment: My customer wants us customize confirm dialog.Besides,I think it  make my site more friendly

Comment: It's not to do with the @ symbol in the email is it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it's the same issue you're looking at. It sounds like the solution is to open the .js file with a text editor and save it as UTF-8 encoding.

Go to "Save with Encoding" menu and choose "UTF-8".

In the Sublime Text 2 this is in File > Save with Encoding > UTF-8.

Comment: try adding this --> Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'  inside config.rb

Comment: Thanks,But after implemented customize confirm dialog,delete link isn't working property. I updated my question please check